# Most efficient way to partially match filenames to textfile and delete accordingly?

Tags: bash, files, youtube-dl

I have a file that has about 1000 entries that look like this:

```
...
U9FzgsF2T-s
...
```

Basicly full of youtube video ids. Then I have a folder that is full of videos that are named like this:

```
007  - James Bond  - Theme-U9FzgsF2T-s.opus
```

Now i would like to delete all files in the folder that don't partially match an entry in the textfile (except for the textfile of course, can't delete that).

Whats an elegant way to do this?
I know I could just loop through all the files and check if they are listed, but at 1000 entries and growing that is gonna take a significant amount of time, especially since this script is executed every few minutes.
So how could I do this efficiently?
Basicly delete every file that doesn't partially match an entry in the folder?

Comment: What writes to the file? Can't that just do `mv *U9FzgsF2T-s* safe/` to move the files corresponding to the ID away?  That way you always know that the files in `safe` are matching the IDs.

Comment: problem is, the file changes, records get added and deleted over time

Comment: That's my point though. You update the ID file, and also the affected files at the same time. It's not even clear that you _need_ the ID file.

Comment: its youtube-dl. Youtube dl basicly just dumps all files in a playlist into a folder and ignores the ones it already downloaded. (annoyingly, its uses its own ID file to keep track of which videos are in the directory already, it just doesn't bother to delete the ones not in the playlist anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `grep -v` a list of the files against the strings in id-list. Something like:

```
printf '%s\0' * | grep -zvF -e ID-LIST -f ID-LIST | xargs -0 echo
```

- Replace `echo` with `rm` to remove the files

---

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: How would I replace the wildcard in a script? ls doesn't seam to work

Comment: Nevermind just made a mistake

Comment: FreeBSD 12.1 has grep with a working/functioning  `-z` option as well.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks for the info